# Why we don't need to de-reference pointer value in case of malloc array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

I am coming across hardship trying to understand how C compiler interprets character arrays, strings, integers, and arrays in a shady way. And thanks for helping me out. Even many of reddit users pointed out that the whole pointer thing in C is a bit shady on how exactly it interprets commands.
So, I am trying to understand `malloc` with an example. But before that this is what I understand.
Say `*p` is a variable. Then p holds the address it's pointing towards.
and `*p` references the value that the address holds.
In case of dynamic allocation,
When I do

```
int *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*5); //say we want 5 locations //
```

And manually loop as the user gives in all 5 values, I put in the values like

```
scanf("%d", p+i) // as p already holds address, I get that we don't have to provide the & . And i being the iterator.. //
```

and then print the same with another loop here's what happens and I have not a clue why.

Say the user inputs **55,66,77,88,99**

When I print using this code,

```
printf("%d", *p+i); // De-referencing the values in location p by using asterics, + the value of iteration,i //
```

I get the values as crazy as **55,56,57,58,59**

So from a little help from internet, I tried the printf code like this and it worked like a charm, but
I didn't have to even de-reference. Why the heck is this so confusing?

```
printf("%d", p[i]); // No asterics used. How does the compiler know I want the value and not the address? as p only should hold the addresses, and *p should give us the values in those addresses //
```

Also, somehow if I do `printf("%d", *p++);`
Then also it works.
Why I am not getting how C works?

Also on the same note, if I try to do the same but this time with `scanf("%d", p[i]);`, then syntax error.
I mean why?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int *p = ....
```

Here, `p` is a variable of type `int *`, which means, variable `p` is a pointer which can hold the address of an `int` type.

The in memory view of allocated and initialised memory, pointed by `p`, would be something like this:

```
p ______
       |
      \|/
     --------------------------
     | 55 | 66 | 77 | 88 | 99 |
     --------------------------
```

You are correct on statement `scanf("%d", p+i);` -
`// as p already holds address, I get that we don't have to provide the &.....`

**Question I:**

> *When I print using this code,*

```
printf("%d", *p+i); // De-referencing the values in location p by using asterics, + the value of iteration,i //
```

> *I get the values as crazy as 55,56,57,58,59*

The [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) of unary `*` (indirection) operator is higher than binary `+` operator.
So, the expression `*p+i` will be evaluated as - `(*p)+i`.

Note that operator precedence is the priority for grouping different types of operators with their operands.

When you have `printf("%d", *p+i);` statement in a loop body which is iterating the given allocated array from `i = 0` to `i < 5` -
In the first iteration: (`i = 0` and pointer `p` is pointing to first element of array which is `55`):

```
(*p) + 0  ->  55 + 0  ->  55
```

In the second iteration: (`i = 1` and pointer `p` is pointing to first element of array which is `55`):

```
(*p) + 1  ->  55 + 1  ->  56
```

..... so on
.....

In the fifth iteration: (`i = 4` and pointer `p` is pointing to first element of array which is `55`):

```
(*p) + 4  ->  55 + 4  ->  59
```

Hence you are getting output - 55,56,57,58,59.

To get the expected output, group the operator with operands explicitely - `*(p + i)`.

With this, first the value of `i` will be added to pointer and then the resultant pointer (address) will be dereferenced.

**Question II:**

> *I tried the printf code like this and it worked like a charm, but I didn't have to even de-reference. Why the heck is this so confusing?*

```
printf("%d", p[i]); // No asterics used. How does the compiler know I want the value and not the address? as p only should hold the addresses, and *p should give us the values in those addresses //
```

From C Standard#6.5.2.1:

> The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))).

By this definition of subscript operator -

```
p[i] -> *((p) + (i)) -> *(p + i)
```

That means, `p[i]` and `*(p + i)` are equivalent.
I have already showed you above in the answer that - why `*(p + i)` will give expected output.
Hence, when using `p[i]` you are getting expected output.

**Question III:**

> *Also, somehow if I do `printf("%d", *p++);` Then also it works. Why I am not getting how C works?*

Again, check the operator precedence table and you will find that precedence of `++` (postfix increment) operator is higher than unary `*` (indirection) operator.
So, the expression `*p++` will be evalauted as `*(p++)`.

The post increment operator increase the value of operand by `1` but the value of the expression is the operand's original value prior to the increment operation.

When you have `printf("%d", *p++);` statement in a loop body which is iterating the given allocated array -
In the first iteration: pointer `p` is pointing to first element of array which is the element at `0`<sup>th</sup> index.

```
*(p++) -> p will be incremented but the value of p in the expression will be its value prior to the increment operation which is location of element at `0`th index
       -> *(0th location address) -> 55
```

In the second iteration: pointer `p` is pointing to second element of array which is the element at `1`<sup>st</sup> index.

```
*(p++) -> p will be incremented but the value of p in the expression will be its value prior to the increment operation which is location of element at `1`st index
       -> *(1st location address) -> 66
```

...... so on
......

In the fifth iteration: pointer `p` is pointing to fifth element of array which is the element at `4`<sup>th</sup> index.

```
*(p++) -> p will be incremented but the value of p in the expression will be its value prior to the increment operation which is location of element at `4`th index
       -> *(4th location address) -> 99
```

and `p` is now pointing to one element past the end of array.

You will get expected output - 55,66,77,88,99.

**Question IV:**

> *Also on the same note, if I try to do the same but this time with `scanf("%d", p[i]);`, then syntax error. I mean why?*

Revisit the definition of subscript operator above in the answer and recall that you are aware of fact that `scanf()` expect the address of variable (pointer) as argument.

```
p[i] -> *((p) + (i)) -> *(p + i)
```

`*(p + i)` ==> dereferencing the pointer `p + i` which will give value at that location.
So, `p[i]` is not the address of `i`<sup>th</sup> location of array but its the value at `i`<sup>th</sup> location of array. Hence, you are getting error when passing `p[i]` as argument to `scanf()`.

To get the address of `i`<sup>th</sup> location, just add `&` operation before `p[i]` -

```
scanf("%d", &p[i]);
```

This will work as expected. Again confused, why??

Check this -

```
&p[i] -> &(p[i]) -> &(*((p) + (i)) -> ((p) + (i)) -> p + i
          |                |
  Precedence of operator   |
  [] is higher than        |
  & operator               |
                           |
      The operator & is used to get the address and the operator * is used for dereferencing.
      These operators cancel the effect of each other when used one after another.
```

Hence, the statement

```
scanf("%d", &p[i]);
```

is equivalent to this statement

```
scanf("%d", p + i);
```

and you know very well why `p + i` works fine when given as argument in `scanf()`.

Let me know if you have any further question or confusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's pretty clear to me, that the shady comment I was giving is based on compiler's choice of precedence. Thanks. I know a lot more now.

Answer (score 3):

> Say *p is a variable

No. The variable is `p` and its type is `int*`.

---

- `*p`: the value found at address `p`
- `*p+i` parsed as `(*p) + 1`: the value at address `p` then add the value `1` to that value
- `p[i]` equivalent with `*(p + i)`: the value at address `p + i` where `p + i` is the address of the `i`th element of an array of ints that starts at `p`. A.k.a. the `i`th element in the vector of ints starting at `p`
- `*p++` parsed as `*(p++)`: increment the pointer `p` (i.e. make `p` point at the next element) and get the value from the old value of `p`.

Comment: Re "*The variable is `p` and its type is `int*`.*", That's the `int* p` view of the world. The `int *p` view of the world is that `*p` is an object of type `int`.

Comment: @ikegami I respectfully disagree. In the declaration `int* p` the variable declared is `p` and the type of the variable being declared is `int *`. Outside of the declaration `*p` is an expression comprised of the deference unary operator applied to the id `p` and yes it evaluates to an object of type `int`. But a variable is denoted by a symbol (identifier) and that identifier is `p` that is the name of the variable.

Comment: Re "*I respectfully disagree*", Yet you almost repeated what I said word for word. I 100% agree with what you said, and it doesn't contradict what I said earlier.

Comment: @ikegami then I misunderstood you and I apologize.

Comment: @ikegami: `*p` is an *expression* of type `int` that happens to be an lvalue, but it is not an *object* of type `int`.  Thinking of it that way will just sow confusion.  Replace `p` with a function call that returns a pointer - `*f()` could still be an lvalue, but would you seriously consider it an *object*?

Comment: @John Bode, How could you seriously not consider an `int` not an object? [Quoting](https://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace) [Bjarne Stroustrup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup), "*A "typical C programmer" writes "`int *p;`" and explains it "`*p` is what is the `int`" emphasizing syntax, and may point to the C (and C++) declaration grammar to argue for the correctness of the style. Indeed, the `*` binds to the name p in the grammar.*" (Code tags added)

Comment: @ikegami: `p` is an object.  `*p` is an expression, it’s an lvalue that designates an object, but it is not an object in and of itself.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `p[i]` is exactly equivalent to `*(p + i)` - given a starting address `p`, compute the address of the `i`'th *object* (not byte!) following that address and dereference the result.

You don’t use the `*` operator because there’s an implicit dereference in the subscript operation.

`*p + i` is equivalent to writing `p[0] + i` - you dereference `p` and add the value of `i` to the result, which is why you got the sequence `55, 56, 57, 58, 59` when you were expecting `55, 66, 77, 88, 99`.

Life is easier when you use array notation - just write `p[i]` when you want the `i`'th object in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I think a small runnable code will help you better understand than me explaining.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
    int *q = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
    int i = 0;
    int test_val = 100;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        *(p + i) = test_val;
        q[i] = test_val;
        test_val = test_val + 10;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("p[%d] = %d\n", i, p[i]);

    printf("p[i] gives the value in array p at index i \n\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("q[%d] = %d\n", i, q[i]);
    
    printf("Note that the values in p and q are equal which means that *(x + 1) and x[i] are 2 ways to access the same values \n\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("*p + %d = %d\n", i, *p + i);

    printf("*p + i gets value pointed by p and adds i to it in each iteration \n\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("*(p + %d) = %d\n", i, *(p + i));

    printf("*(p + i) gets value pointed by p + i \n\n");

    int *j = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
    int *k = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
    int *l = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*5);

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         j[i] = test_val;
         k[i] = test_val;
         l[i] = test_val;
    }
    printf("(*j)++ = %d\n\n", (*j)++);
    printf("*(k++) = %d\n\n", *(k++));
    printf("*l++ = %d\n\n", *l++);
    
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         j[i] = test_val;
         k[i] = test_val;
         l[i] = test_val;
    }
    printf("test_val = %d\n\n", test_val);
    printf("++(*j) = %d\n\n", ++(*j));
    printf("*(++k) = %d\n\n", *(++k));
    printf("*++l = %d\n\n", *++l);
    return 0;
}
```

Following is the output:

```
p[0] = 100
p[1] = 110
p[2] = 120
p[3] = 130
p[4] = 140
p[i] gives the value in array p at index i 

q[0] = 100
q[1] = 110
q[2] = 120
q[3] = 130
q[4] = 140
Note that the values in p and q are equal which means that *(x + 1) and x[i] are 2 ways to access the same values 

*p + 0 = 100
*p + 1 = 101
*p + 2 = 102
*p + 3 = 103
*p + 4 = 104
*p + i gets value pointed by p and adds i to it in each iteration 

*(p + 0) = 100
*(p + 1) = 110
*(p + 2) = 120
*(p + 3) = 130
*(p + 4) = 140
*(p + i) gets value pointed by p + i 

test_val = 150

(*j)++ = 150

*(k++) = 150

*l++ = 150

test_val = 150

++(*j) = 151

*(++k) = 150

*++l = 150
```

For the scanf question, scanf always needs a pointer as a parameter. p[I] is the value at (p + i) and thus is incorrect. Ideally, you should use scanf("%d", &(p[i]))

Answer (score 0):

> "*When I print using this code `printf("%d", *p+i);` ... I get the values as crazy as `55`,`56`,`57`,`58`,`59`*"

When you use `*p + i`, `p` is dereferenced first (which gains the value of the first array element, which is `55`) and then `i` is added to the value `55`. `*p + i` is equal to `(*p) + i`.

This is why you get the output of: `55`,`56`,`57`,`58`,`59` and not `55`,`66`,`77`,`88`,`99`

You just add `i` to the value of the first element in each iteration and never access the following 4 array elements.

> "*I tried the `printf` code like this and it worked like a charm, but I didn't have to even de-reference. .... `printf("%d", p[i]);`*"

When you use `p[i]`, you get the value at the `i`th element of the array as it offsets the pointer itself before dereferencing. It is equal to `*(p + i)`.

> "*Also, somehow if I do `printf("%d", *p++);` Then also it works.*"

When you use `*p++`, `p` is actual dereferenced and the value at `*p` is gained but thereafter `p` is incremented. Means at the next iteration `p` points to the next array element.

After the loop has been completed, `p` points one past the array.

---

> "*If I try to do the same but this time with `scanf("%d", p[i]);`, then syntax error. I mean why?*"

For `scanf()` the things are a little bit different.

When you use `scanf("%d", p[i]);`, `p[i]` is equal to `*(p + i)` as it is also in the `printf()` calls but as you try to dereference and gain an `int` object and not a pointer to `int`, which is needed for `%d` at `scanf()`, it is a syntax error.

In `scanf()`, `%d` requires an argument of type `int *`, not `int`.

---

For your main question:

> "*Why we don't need to de-reference pointer value in case of malloc array?*"

It has nothing to do with `malloc()`ed or dynamic memory allocation in particular. It has something to do with pointer arithmetic syntax allowed in C.